# This Field leaks context object

Tags: android

I am using Context object inside non-Activity, it is working perfectly but the problem is it shows warning

That is where I am using the context object
[image]

Here is the result of inspection
[image]

Comment: That just means the lint works correctly, it *does* leak the activity context. Is there any reason why it is not application context?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: At the surface it may look like it's working perfectly but in reality it's not. The garbage collector can't collect the Activity and your app will keep using more and more memory until the device runs out of memory and your app crashes. To prevent this you can use either the Application context or a WeakReference to the Activity Context. If you have no clue what this means I suggest you google "android context memory leak" and read some of the many articles/blogposts you'll find.

Comment: Or just don't directly pass Activity context at all

Comment: Yes, You're right it seems like everything ok but it is not because I have searched lots of websites and realized that I have to use Activity context or weak reference. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 20):

You can use [WeakReferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) for this case. something like this:

```
public class ContactsTask {

    private WeakReference<Context> weakContext;

    public ContactsTask(Context context){
        weakContext = new WeakReference<>(context);
    }

    public void doSomething(){
        if (weakContext!=null) weakContext.get() ...    //return context without leaks
    }

}
```