# Will the context of Service() cause "This field leaks a context object"?

Tags: android

I have read the articals

[This Field leaks context object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48381818/this-field-leaks-context-object/48382073)

[This field leaks a context object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46797916/this-field-leaks-a-context-object/46798014)

[Getting a "this field leaks a context object" when passing a context from Main Activity to Java Class via Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56484429/getting-a-this-field-leaks-a-context-object-when-passing-a-context-from-main-a)

The Code `private var mService: RecordService? = null`  show a warning *"This field leaks a context object"* ? why?

I think that `HomeViewModel` object will be destroyed after `Activity` object destroyed, and the `mService` will be released too, why does Android Studio display *"This field leaks a context object"* ?

```
class HomeViewModel(private val mApplication: Application, private val mDBVoiceRepository: DBVoiceRepository) : AndroidViewModel(mApplication) {

    private var mService: RecordService? = null

    private val serviceConnection = object : ServiceConnection {
        override fun onServiceConnected(className: ComponentName, iBinder: IBinder) {
            val binder = iBinder as RecordService.MyBinder
            mService = binder.service
           
        }      
    }

   fun bindService() {
        Intent(mApplication , RecordService::class.java).also { intent ->
            mApplication.bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
        }
    }

    fun unbindService() {
        Intent(mApplication, RecordService::class.java).also { intent ->
            mApplication.unbindService(serviceConnection)
            mService?.stopForeground(true)
            mService?.stopSelf()
        }
    }
    ...
}



class RecordService : Service() {
    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder {
        return MyBinder()
    }

    inner class MyBinder : Binder() {
        val service: RecordService
            get() = this@RecordService
    }

    ...
}
```

**Added Content**

To AlphaOne: Thanks!

I still get the warning *"This field leaks a context object"* when I use the following code, how can I do if I need call `RecordService` in `HomeViewModel`?

```
    class HomeViewModel(private val mApplication: Application, 
                        private val mDBVoiceRepository: DBVoiceRepository,
                        private var mService: RecordService?) : 
             AndroidViewModel(mApplication) {
    
    
    }
```

And more, the following code is source code of `AndroidViewModel` , it seems that Android doesn't do extra works for the class  `AndroidViewModel`, it seems that android prevent to display the warning information.

```
public class AndroidViewModel extends ViewModel {
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private Application mApplication;

    public AndroidViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        mApplication = application;
    }

    /**
     * Return the application.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({"TypeParameterUnusedInFormals", "unchecked"})
    @NonNull
    public <T extends Application> T getApplication() {
        return (T) mApplication;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Official docs:

> A ViewModel must never reference a view, Lifecycle, or any class that
> may hold a reference to the activity context.

Since the services have their own lifecycle and are managed by Operating Systems, you shouldn't keep its reference inside the ViewModel.

During configuration change, the ViewModel is preserved, so still may have reference to Service and will cause the memory leak.

Comment: Thanks! If I launch `unbindService()` in  `override fun onCleared() { }` of  the ViewModel object, will it be Ok?

Comment: You shouldn't. mService is leaking the context and it's used in unbindService().

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: Hey, why you want mService in ViewModel? ViewModel's only responsibility is to manage the data for the UI. It should never access your view hierarchy or hold a reference back to the Activity or the Fragment or the service.